# MySQL: Return first three entries from table sorted by distance: giving latitude and logitude as params

Tags: mysql

I tried:

```
var latitude = K.params.latitude
var longitude = K.params.longitude

var sqlString = "SELECT name, latitude, longitude, SQRT( \
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - '"+latitude+"'), 2) + \
    POW(69.1 * ('"+longitude+"' - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance \
FROM 10561_12865_tblEvents HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance"

var results = K.query(sqlString, [])
```

But this returns only 1 result, sometimes none when it should have.

Do you have a better solution for me?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ST_Distance_Sphere(point(lonA,latA), point(lonB,latB))`

For example:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(point(0, 0), point(180, 0)) as distance
```

You can find out more at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself using the following function

```
var latitude = K.params.latitude
var longitude = K.params.longitude
var start = K.params.start
var count = K.params.count
var maxDistanceKM = K.params.maxDistanceInKM

var sqlString = "SELECT *,\
    ( 6371.25 * acos( \
            cos( radians('"+latitude+"') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('"+longitude+"') ) + sin( radians('"+latitude+"') )  * sin( radians( latitude ) ) )  ) AS distance \
FROM 10561_12865_tblEvents \
HAVING distance < '"+maxDistanceKM+"' \
ORDER BY distance \
LIMIT "+start+" , "+count
```